The behavior of Riemann zeta function zeta(s) when the imaginary part of s is smaller than 2
I am reading some analytical properties of Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ on some analytical number theory books. The upper bound is well written on these books. For example, such theorems are stated in G.Tenenbaum's book Introduction to analytical and probabilistic number theory Chapter §3.10 Bounds for Riemann zeta function
or in some other materials Upper bounds for $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta'(s)$. However, the upper bounds of Riemann zeta function are all defined in the region where the imaginary part of $s$ should be bigger than a number like 2 or 3. I wonder does similar bound ever exist when the imaginary part of $s$ is below 2?
I want to get the upper bound of $\zeta(s)$ in the region $D$ where
$|t|=|\Im(s)|\le 2$ and $1>\sigma=\Re(s)\ge 1-\frac{A}{(\log|t|)^9}$ such that $\zeta(s)$ does not have any zeros. The analyticity of $\zeta(s)$ in the region $R=\{s:\Re(s)>0,s\neq 1 \}$ implies that $|\zeta(s)|$ is uniformly bounded in any compact rectangle contained in R. Can this argument just show that in region $D$, $\zeta(s)$ is bounded by some constant?
Revise the above argument:
Since $\zeta(s)$ is analytic in $\sigma \ge 1$ except for a simple pole $s=1$, $(s-1){\zeta(s)}$ is analytic in $\sigma \ge 1$ except for a simple pole $s=1$. By compactness the analyticity extends to a region of the form $\sigma \ge 1-B$, $|t|\le 2$, where $B$ is a sufficiently small constant. It follows that this function is bounded in the compact region $1-B\le \sigma \le 2$, $|t|\le 2$, so that we have $(s-1){\zeta(s)}≪1 \iff \zeta(s)≪\frac{1}{s-1}\iff |\zeta(s)|≪\frac{1}{|s-1|}$.

In such cases, the pole at $s=1$ dominates its behavior. One may write $\zeta(s) = 1/(s-1) + O(1)$ when imaginary part and real part of $s$ are bounded.

@ Kangyeon Moon Thanks for your comment. I have just revised my question. Do you think my argument is sufficient?

No. $D$ is not a compact subset of $R$. Since $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$, it diverges as $s\to 1$, and you cannot find a constant upper bound. But you can write $\zeta(s) = 1/(s-1) + O(1)$ or more crudely $\zeta(s) \ll 1/|s-1|$.

@ Kangyeon Moon I change the definition for the desired region. Is the argument now valid?

But can I just let B=A/(log|t|)^9 in the previous definition by setting appropriate A. Will there be any problem?

It looks ok. If you consider the region $\sigma>1-A/(\log|t|)^9$, first the region goes farther to the left beyond the line $\sigma = 0$ for $|t|$ little larger than $1$, and when $|t|<1$ the region goes farther to the right beyond the line $\sigma=1$. Thus if you let instead $\sigma>1-A/(\log(|t|+2))^9$ for instance, there is no problem since this covers smaller region than $\sigma>1-A/(\log 2)^9$.
